# Output Azure Function powershell value to azure storage account

Tags: powershell, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I have a powershell script running in an azure function app that grabs a json list of IPs, parses it and just returns a list of IPs with 1 per line. I need to take this output and save it to a specific azure storage account. I'm attempting to use the static website in the storage account to create an HTTP endpoint for others to retrieve the list of IPs.

Here's the script

```
# Input bindings are passed in via param block.
param($Timer)

# Get the current universal time in the default string format.
$currentUTCtime = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()

# The 'IsPastDue' property is 'true' when the current function invocation is later than scheduled.
if ($Timer.IsPastDue) {
    Write-Host "PowerShell timer is running late!"
}

# Write an information log with the current time.
Write-Host "PowerShell timer trigger function ran! TIME: $currentUTCtime"

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

$url = "https://ip-ranges.atlassian.com/"

Invoke-RestMethod $url

$iplist = Invoke-RestMethod $url

$iplist.items | select-object -ExpandProperty cidr

out-file $outputBlob
```

I've tested the function in azure and it runs there just fine. I can't seem to get the integration outputs section of the function app to work. The settings for the outputs is

```
Binding type - azure blob storage
blob paramter name - outputBlob
Path - test/list.txt
storage account connection - searched and selected the storage account
```

I am not finding much documentation on how to make my powershell script output to this storage account. The out-file clearly doesn't work.

----------- **updated code** ----------

Here is the code that now successfully saves the file to a container, but I still cant save to the $web container for the static website. The $ is not something I can use in the output binding

```
# Input bindings are passed in via param block.
param($Timer)

# Get the current universal time in the default string format.
$currentUTCtime = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()

# The 'IsPastDue' property is 'true' when the current function invocation is later than scheduled.
if ($Timer.IsPastDue) {
    Write-Host "PowerShell timer is running late!"
}

# Write an information log with the current time.
Write-Host "PowerShell timer trigger function ran! TIME: $currentUTCtime"


#------------------------

$url = "https://ip-ranges.atlassian.com/" 

Invoke-RestMethod $url

$call = Invoke-RestMethod $url

$iplist = $call.items | select-object -ExpandProperty cidr

$output = out-string -InputObject $iplist

Push-OutputBinding -Name outputBlob -Value $output
```

the outputBlob binding is configured under integration > outputs > and the Path which is in the format of container/file. I cannot specify $web/file.txt...but if I do web/file.txt it will create a web container and put the output as file.txt within it. I need to do this, but it must go in the $web container.

Comment: Would this be what you're after? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-powershell

Comment: Not sure how that would work. Looks like it requires local storage to copy a file to the storage account from

Comment: I don't see any `push-outputbinding` statement. It has been some time since I wrote PS azure functions but everything that need to be output (as I remember it) need to go through that cmdlet. If you want to output to a storage account, that is also the way to go. More specifically, check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-output?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-powershell).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is something that I've been meaning to try for a little while but not actually got around to. Decided to give it a shot today when I seen your question.

So it is possible to push content using the blob output binding but the functionality is limited.

#### run.ps1

```
using namespace System.Net

# Input bindings are passed in via param block.
param (
    $Request,
    $TriggerMetadata
)

# Call the atlassian API to get the address ranges
$atlassianUri = "https://ip-ranges.atlassian.com/"
$iplist = Invoke-RestMethod $atlassianUri -ErrorAction Stop
$cidrList = $iplist.items | select-object -ExpandProperty cidr

# Push the contents to blob storage using the outputBinding
Push-OutputBinding -Name myOutputBlob -Value $cidrList

# Return a simple response so I know it worked
Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{
    StatusCode = [HttpStatusCode]::OK
    Body = 'Successfully Updated Blob Storage'
})
```

#### function.json

You would have to include an timer Input Binding in your function but I used HTTP so that I could trigger it on-demand to test that it would work.

I have provided a static path to the blob output binding. The `Path` property can not be dynamically assigned from within the function yet according to [this open GitHub issue.](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-powershell-worker/issues/772)

```json
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "Request",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "Response"
    },
    {
      "name": "myOutputBlob",
      "type": "blob",
      "path": "functioncopy/ipRanges.txt",
      "connection": "MyStorageConnectionAppSetting",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ]
}
```

The above code works however when sending the data to the blob file in the storage account `Push-OutputBinding` serialises the content to a JSON array e.g.

[image: Storage Account Screenshot]

This may or may not work for you in it's current guise but I don't think there is a way using the output binding to just have a raw list.

You could however use the `Az.Storage` module within your function, create the file within your function execution and upload it that way instead

#### run.ps1

```
# Variables required - Fill these out
$storageAccountName = '<Insert Storage Account Here'
$containerName = '<Insert StorageContainer Name Here>'
$resourceGroupName = '<Insert resourceGroup Name Here>'
$subscriptionId = '<Insert subscriptionId Here>'

# Call the atlassian API to get the address ranges
$atlassianUri   = "https://ip-ranges.atlassian.com/"
$iplist         = Invoke-RestMethod $atlassianUri -ErrorAction Stop
$cidrList       = $iplist.items | select-object -ExpandProperty cidr

# New-TemporaryFile uses [System.IO.Path]::GetTempPath() location
$tempFile = New-TemporaryFile

# Set the context to the subscription you want to use
# If your functionApp has access to more than one subscription it will load the first subscription by default.
# Possibly a good habit to be explicit about context.
Set-AzContext -Subscription $subscriptionId

# Get the Storage Account Key to authenticate
$storAccKeys = Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $storageAccountName
$primaryKey = $storAccKeys | Where-Object keyname -eq 'key1' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty value

# Write the CIDR list to the temp file created earlier
$cidrList | Out-File $tempFile

# Create a Storage Context which will be used in the subsequent commands
$storageContext = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $primaryKey

# Upload the temp file to blob storage
$setAzStorageBlobContentSplat = @{
    Container  = $containerName
    File       = $tempFile.FullName
    Blob       = 'ipranges.txt'
    Context    = $storageContext
    Properties = @{
        ContentType = 'text/plain'
    }
}

Set-AzStorageBlobContent @setAzStorageBlobContentSplat

# Return a simple response so I know it worked
Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value (
    [HttpResponseContext]@{
        StatusCode = [HttpStatusCode]::OK
        Body       = 'Successfully Updated Blob Storage'
    }
)
```

You can see the documentation on Set-AzStorageBlobContent for examples on that here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/set-azstorageblobcontent?view=azps-6.2.1#examples

Comment: I made it work by adding the following code since the function app was integrated with my storage account.

Push-OutputBinding -Name outputBlob -Value $output

However, I really need to put this in the $web container to use the static website. You cannot specify a $ character in the path of the output binding though. Testing works flawlessly at a path of container1/test.txt. But I need to get this file output to the $web container to be able to pull it up in the browser. That's the last part I need to make this work, but haven't seen any way to do this

Comment: I just tested changing the `path` in the `function.json` to `"path": "$web/ipRanges.txt"` and it was able to add and create the $web container on function invocation.

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/98588118/159340843-edc0b04c-779d-45d8-b0b9-160b1359714b.png

Comment: That did get the file into the $web container, which is another step forward! However when you browse to that .txt file created through the function, it downloads rather than renders it in the browser. If I manually upload a .txt file to the $web container, it shows in the browser as I would expect. It appears the content type is different though. This script makes it application/octet-stream, while my manual uploads that work as expected are text/plain. Any idea how to make it text/plain?

Comment: I've added the code below, which doesn't error, but also doesn't actually change the content type. It's still octet-steam when you check in the storage account


Push-OutputBinding -Name outputBlob -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{
    headers = @{'content-type'='text/plain'}
    Body = $output
})

Comment: I think this may be a limitation of the `Push-OutputBinding` format. The file format will be set in the binding code. You may have to use the `Az.Storage` alternative method that I posted above to be specific about file types uploaded.

Comment: same result doing it the second way you mentioned. Had to add the -context flag as it was missing, but it does drop a file successfully in $web container. 

Same issue remains though where the content-type is not plain/text. Are you familiar with changing the content-type? application/octet-stream is what it defaults too but I need it to be plain/text

Comment: I've updated my original `run.ps1` with code that works and also sets the MIME type of the uploaded documnt to text/plain. I've tested that this is reflected in the storage account but I don't have a static website configured.

Comment: that was it. I also have a case open with MS support where they are going to verify that the inability to change content-type is an output binding limitation. I would also add you need the -Force flag on a recurring script or else it will error because a user isn't approving a prompt to replace the existing file

Comment: did confirm with microsoft that you cannot change the content-type with output binding. So really, the best way to approach this for the widest range of usecases is with the examples above in powershell where you are specifying and setting the contet-type to text/plain, or whatever else you want