# Powershell Azure Function to write an Excel file to Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I need to write a Powershell Azure Function that reads data from an API and write it as excel file to Azure Blob Storage.
I created the following output binding in `function.json`

```
    {
      "type": "blob",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "outputBlob",
      "path": "mydir/test-file.xlsx",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage"
    }
```

Next I have the following powershell azure function

```
using namespace System.Net

# Input bindings are passed in via param block.
param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)

# Write to the Azure Functions log stream.
Write-Host "PowerShell HTTP trigger function processed a request."

$Test = Get-Module | Export-Excel -PassThru 

# Push data to blob storage 
Push-OutputBinding -Name outputBlob -Value $Test

# Associate values to output bindings by calling 'Push-OutputBinding'.
Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{
    StatusCode = [HttpStatusCode]::OK
    Body = $body
})
```

I get the following error when testing locally:

```
Exception: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Drawing.Common, Version=4.0.2.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Not sure if it's possible to generate an Excel file on blob storage, but would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be a possible issue with ImportExcel. Some information here

See here: https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel/issues/1114#issuecomment-989991024

Not sure whether you'd have to downgrade ImportExcel module version but may be worth raising an issue on the repo.

As for outputting the file to blob storage you'll likely be better ditching the blob storage output binding and using the Az.Storage commands.

Previously answered a question here on
[Output Azure Function powershell value to azure storage account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71552035)